# IceFaces duplicate entries in combos, menus after layout change

Tags: java, icefaces

My IceFaces 1.8 based application starts with a very simple xhtml that includes a different one based on a bean's property. This property is bound to a combo's item that is included in every page. If the user selects a layout from this combo, the page updates to the new layout.

It is all ok, except that after every single page layout change, the items in the layout selector combo get duplicated, triplicated and so on.

This is the "multiplexer" xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component">

    <ui:include src="#{system.layout}">
    </ui:include>

</html>
```

And this is the layout selector that is included into every layout xhtml:

```
  <ice:form id="layoutSelectForm">
        <ice:outputLabel for="layoutSelector">#{msgs['LayoutSelect.Label']}: </ice:outputLabel>
        <ice:selectOneMenu id="layoutSelector" binding="#{layoutSelect.som}" value="#{layoutSelect.selectedLayout}" 
            valueChangeListener="#{layoutSelect.processValueChange}" partialSubmit="true">
            <f:selectItems value="#{layoutSelect.allLayouts}" />
        </ice:selectOneMenu >
  </ice:form>
```

Here is the code of the LayoutSelect backing bean:

```
public class JSFLayoutSelect implements InitializingBean, ValueChangeListener {
    private EventManager eventManager;
    private String mainApplFrmURL;
    private HtmlSelectOneMenu som;
    public List<SelectItem> allLayouts;
    private String selectedLayout;

        @Override
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event)
            throws AbortProcessingException {
        eventManager.publish("layout-select/change", event.getNewValue());
        logger.info("Layout changed event occured: " + event.getNewValue());

        try {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(mainApplFrmURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        allLayouts = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        allLayouts.add(new SelectItem("dev", "Core Dev"));
        allLayouts.add(new SelectItem("classic", "Core Classic"));
        allLayouts.add(new SelectItem("modern", "Core Modern"));
        selectedLayout = "dev";
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getAllLayouts() {
        return allLayouts;
    }

    public String getSelectedLayout() {
        return selectedLayout;
    }

        /* some unimportant methods are not here */
}

  <bean name="layoutSelect" class="hu.hgap.comp.impl.JSFLayoutSelect" scope="session">
    <property name="eventManager" ref="SessionEventManager"/>
     <property name="mainApplFrmURL" value="/ICEFacesSpringDemoV2/secured/ApplFrm.faces" />
  </bean>
```

Can you tell me what shall I do to avoid duplicating combo entries? I see that after changing the layout the very same combo gets rendered again and the combo items are pushed into it again from the server.

Comment: Can you post the code for your backing bean? Also could you say how the list allLayouts gets constructed in the bean? Thanks.

Comment: @MatthieuF: I added the backing bean's code to my question, as you can see the list is set after the bean is initialized. As it is of session scope it happens only once a session. I debugged to double check the list is not duplicated the server side, only client side.

Comment: the question is still there, maybe I'll start a bounty to make it more desirable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your backing bean look like? Which scope does it have?

I had similar experience with binding variables in a session scope bean. When I moved the variable to a request scopre bean the problem disappeared.

Comment: The backing bean is of session scope, but I cannot change it because the layout selection is something that should be per session. AFAIK request scope means that the bean is reset every HTTP request, isn't it?